# Inserting image tag inside a template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to insert an image depending on a state - but this will display the string of img src=${redExclamation} .

```
return `${
    isEmpty
        ? `<img src=${redExclamation} />`
        : `<img src=${greenCheck} /> `
    }`;
```

I've tried it a different way where i got rid of the string literal:

```
return `${
    isEmpty
        ? <img src=${redExclamation} />
        : <img src=${greenCheck} />
    }`;
```

But this will show [object Object] in the HTML. Not sure what I should be doing here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to return just `return isEmpty ? \`<img src=${redExclamation} />\`  : \`<img src=${greenCheck} />\``

Comment: Is there more inside the template literal, or could you just move the logic into the `src` property and use a regular JSX element for the `<img />`? (E.g. `<img src={ \`Your template string here\` } />`)

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I asume that you are using react and that you try to return a jsx html literal. If so it might be useful to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a string, not html.

```
return isEmpty
        ? <img src={redExclamation} />
        : <img src={greenCheck} />;
```

Might be what you need

Comment: That won't work - the OP is trying to return a string value containing the necessary image tag and filename.

Comment: @Paul The question isn't particularly clear, but I would interpret this to be the correct approach. There is no request for the result to be a string in the question, only "I'm trying to insert an image depending on a state"

Answer (score 0):

You can try without the outer literal like the following:

```
return isEmpty ? `<img src=${redExclamation} />` : `<img src=${greenCheck} />`
```

Or if you're trying to return a jsx you should do it as per [docs](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)